# Pythonの文字コードに関して

Tags: python

Python初心者です。
BeautifulSoupを使ってスクレイピングを試みたのですがどうも文字コードに関する知識が乏しくうまくいきません。

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html2 = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, "html.parser")
tag = soup.findAll("p", attrs={"class":"txt"})  
a = str(tag)
```

とってきたテキストの文字コードを見てみたら

```
print chardet.detect(a)
{confidence:1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
```

という結果になりました。
そこでファイルに書き込む際、文字コードをShift-jisにしたくいろいろ試みたのですがうまくいきませんでした。

どなたか解決策を知ってる方がいらっしゃたら書き込みお願いします。

追記：http://www.goo-net.com/php/car_review/detail_list.php?car_cd=10101044
こちらのサイトの口コミのテキストをスクレイピングしようとしてます。

Comment: 読み込んでいるhtmlはShift-JISですか？

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` は、正しくパースができた場合にはユニコードとして保持するように思いますので、まずは正しくパースができているかどうかという時点での切り分けが必要なように思います。`BeautifulSoup`が文字コードを間違ってパースしているような場合には、文字コードを指定してパースすることもできたかと思います。ユニコード文字列をシフトJISで出力できないというのが問題なのであればその変換部分のコードを追記しましょう。

Comment: Kenji Noguchi様
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-JP" />と六行目に宣言されていたのでEUC-JPということになるのでしょうか？

Comment: BLUEPIXY様

print isinstance(soup,unicode)で調べた結果、Falseと出たのですがこの場合パースに失敗しているということでしょうか？
soup=BeautifulSoup(html2,"html.parser",from_encoding="euc-jp")と変えてみたのですが、Falseから変化はありませんでした。。

Answer (score 2):

str(tag)がまちがっているだけだと思います。次のようにしてSJISのファイルが作れました。

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.goo-net.com/php/car_review/detail_list.php?car_cd=10101044'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
html=urllib2.urlopen(req)
html2=html.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html2,"html.parser")
tags=soup.findAll("p",attrs={"class":"txt"})
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for t in tags:
        print >>f, t.encode('cp932')
```

**蛇足**

ちなみにPyQueryを使うと、こんな風に書けます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

url = 'http://www.goo-net.com/php/car_review/detail_list.php?car_cd=10101044'

dom = pq(url)

with open('output2.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for p in dom('p.txt').items():
        print >>f, p.text().encode('cp932')
```

Comment: 上記に書いたコードを実行した結果Shift-jisのファイルを作ることができました！ずっとつまづいていたところだったので本当にありがとうございます！
PyQueryを使うとこんなに簡潔なコードが書けるんですね！今度勉強してみます！

今回は本当にありがとうございました。